# Limit with parameter, $(e^{-1/x^2})/x^a$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How do I explore for which values of the parameter $a$

$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^a} e^{-1/x^2} = 0?
 $$
For $a=0$ it is true, but I don't know what other values.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Put $y=1/x$ and note that $ y \to \infty $.

$$ \lim_{y\to \infty} y^a e^{-y^2} = \dots. $$

Answer (score 2):

It's true for all $a's$ (note that for $a\leqslant 0$ it's trivial) and you can prove it easily using L'Hopital's rule or Taylor's series for $\exp(-x^2)$.

Comment: So the answer is any $a$?

Answer (score 0):

- If $a\leq 0$, then it is immediate that the limit is $0$.
- If $a>0$, then: for $a=1$ and $a=2$ you can check it easily.

If $x\to0^+$, then the limit can be written $\lim\limits_{u\to+\infty}u^ae^{-u^2}=\lim\limits_{u\to+\infty}\dfrac{u^a}{e^{u^2}}\overset{DLH}{=} \lim\limits_{u\to+\infty} \dfrac{au^{a-1}}{2ue^{u^2}}=\dfrac{a}{2}\lim\limits_{u\to+\infty} \dfrac{u^{a-2}}{e^{u^2}}=0$ by induction.

If $x\to0^-$, then the limit can be written $\lim\limits_{u\to-\infty}u^ae^{-u^2}=\lim\limits_{u\to-\infty}\dfrac{u^a}{e^{u^2}}\overset{DLH}{=} \lim\limits_{u\to-\infty} \dfrac{au^{a-1}}{2ue^{u^2}}=\dfrac{a}{2}\lim\limits_{u\to-\infty} \dfrac{u^{a-2}}{e^{u^2}}=0$ by induction.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**: You may rewrite the equation

$$ \frac{1}{x^a} e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}} = \frac{1}{x^a e^{\frac{1}{x^2}}} = \frac{1}{e^{a \ln(x)+ \frac{1}{x^2}}}$$

Comment: but now we need to calculate $\lim _{x \to 0}a\ln x +\frac{1}{x^2}$. I don't think it's a simpler limit to figure out.